# full backup for deployment and reproduction

Tags: backup, restore

I am currently working on a project on a Geniatech ATV1220 Device running Android 4.2.2. I need some applications on this device with specific settings like Debian Kit with openssh, openvpn, nodejs and also a firefox browser with fullscreen addon as well as a terminal emulator with specific command line.

I have it all set up to work perfectly according to my needs on one box but now I want to achieve the exact same thing on other boxes (also Geniatech ATV1220s), without having to do the process of manually setting up each box individually, since I might have to do it to a lot of boxes.

What would be the best way to backup the whole filesystem including debian kit, all applications, all settings of those applications and all the stored data and then restore it on another device to basically make them 2 identical boxes?

I tried adb backup with the following command:

```
adb backup –all -apk -shared –f backup.ab
```

But that didn't seem to do the trick, as when I restored the backup on another device, debian kit for example wasn't running at all. I also have a way to sign images for that device, which I used to remove unnecessary apps and services, if that helps in any way.

Has anyone had to do something similar and knows the best way to do it?

Kind regards
egon

Comment: I've got no idea about that Debian kit, so please allow me one question: Are all required components registered as "apps" with the system, or is there something installed manually in the file system? Depending on that, I might have some ideas.

Comment: Debian kit is basically a basic linux debian running in parallel to android which then provides the services like nodejs, openssh, openvpn etc. So debiankit itself and those components are not registered as apps.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! In this case, what I had in mind doesn't completely work out. Unless... Is Debian kit installed on its own partition (so you could transfer it by simply "cloning" that)? Would it start then, or does it need some "specific boot loader"? I thought of *Titanium Backup* to create a flashable `.zip` for the Android apps part, and a partition clone for the Debian part. Could that work?

Comment: Debian kit is using its own loop disk file for the image which could be backed up but subdirectories and files (such as /lib or /etc/resolv.conf) are also added to the Android RAM-disk based file system with symlinks or bind-mounts. So it is not separated completely.

Comment: OK, so I've got no complete solution. Maybe the "flashable ZIP" for the Android stuff might be part of it; for the Debian side, someone else must "jump in" with ideas.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the input so far anyway! Will definitely try this out for the app part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding a packed debian image into an android image, which then gets included into the system on the first boot up by a setup application.